# SharePoint 2010: List doesn't show columns while adding new record to it

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have created a custom list definition using visual studio 2010 and deployed it on SP. After that I've created a list using it but while adding items in the list, list doesn't reflect the same columns. Shown in picture below.

[Screenshot of the list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sdNH.png)

In the above picture, in RED box you can see that list is showing 5 columns but In BLUE box i.e. when adding item to list it is showing only 'title' column.

**Code of custom list:**

```
<Fields>
    <Field ID="{E8725875-E115-49D9-A701-F6E15B0259FB}" Name="ListFirstName"     DisplayName="First Name" Type="Text" Required="TRUE"></Field>
    <Field ID="{61335CDB-5D1A-4326-8205-DFE635C66B5B}" Name="ListLastName" DisplayName="Last Name" Type="Text"></Field>
    <Field ID="{2A376F22-4EAC-41D5-840F-D5BA4CE4FCDE}" Name="ListGender" DisplayName="Gender" Type="Choice" Required="TRUE">
        <CHOICES>
            <CHOICE>Male</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>Female</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>Transgender</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>
    <Field ID="{71A23EDC-470F-4E3C-9469-1999922507E6}" Name="ListAge" DisplayName="Age" Type="Number"></Field>
    <Field ID="{39EAC56B-B35E-46E7-97AD-A37A139EE09B}" Name="ListEmail" DisplayName="Email" Type="Text" Required="TRUE"></Field>
</Fields>
```

**AND**

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="ListFirstName"></FieldRef>
    <FieldRef Name="ListLastName"></FieldRef>
    <FieldRef Name="ListGender"></FieldRef>
    <FieldRef Name="ListAge"></FieldRef>
    <FieldRef Name="ListEmail"></FieldRef>
</ViewFields>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you place the **ViewFields** in the right **View**

Details: schema file generated by Visual Studio, generates by default many Views for the same List Instance. Please make sure your put those **ViewFields** under the right **View** partition

**HINT**: you might need to delete this list from SharePoint site, and redeploy the solution again from Visual Studio after applying the solution above.

Comment: There were 2 views, and I placed **ViewFields** under the view with **BaseViewID=1**! Is it correct ?